# making a cover for pipes on the wall

Tags: table-saw, wood, wood-selection

I recently bought a house and I did most of the renovation work in the house. Most of the things are done, I still have some ugly pipes sticking out of the wall, I really don't like them. I want to hide them using some wooden planks. I already got a table saw, to make the necessary straight cuts, since I am very bad at making a straight cut's.

My question is I know what I want to do but I don't know where/how to start. can someone help me by giving some suggestion? How can I accomplish this and what is the best type of wood to use in order to make the covers for the pipes.

cheers

Added later: 
Here is the picture of the pipes.

[image: interior photo showing pipes on wall]

Comment: how big are the pipes and what material are they made of? posting a picture would probably help too.

Comment: This is called 'boxing in' if you want to Google for more info. The framing work is most commonly done using construction wood (2x material) which is generally pine or another similar softwood, on top of that you can use any wood you prefer.

Comment: Now I get it, by sticking out I thought that you have the ends of some unused pipes sticking out of your wall...! I have some pipes in my flat as well, they are plain copper and they quite grew on me :)

Comment: @Stoppal_ so have you done any boxing on those pipes?

Comment: I know this as creating a bulkhead. Also this seems like a much better fit for DIY.SE. Framing lumber would be used around the pipes and then you would just drywall that frame. Make sure that you don't cover up any access points / vents while doing this.

Comment: I had an apartment like this once, and I ended up painting the pipes in an accent color. It's really quite fetching. Your style might not be mine, though.

Comment: Where to start depends on the construction of the house. Does the house have solid interior walls (brick, block, other masonry), or it is wood framed? What kind of covering is on the walls - is it drywall, plaster & lathe, something else?

Comment: Charlie Kilian_ thanks for the suggestion, i was already thinking of coloring the pipe but I want to hide them, just don't want to look at them ;)

Comment: @FreeMan_House has solid interior wall with bricks and its its plastered. I was thinking of making a frame around the pipes and then cover it with the wooden plank. So I was thinking the best way to make the frame around the pipes.

Answer (score 1):

There is really only one option that I could recommend from my experience. Do some boxing-like over the pipes. Cut a board the width of the board and then go the distance you need to go from the wall. Then pain the wood what ever color you have used for the wall. It may not look the best but it would cover the pipes. Otherwise I would think you are better without doing that.

Comment: my main problem is the start point, how and where do I start? I have a idea how I can do the boxing but I am having difficulty with starting it. Any suggestion for me?

Comment: Well, depending on how the pipes start you could but the wood on the wall and work your way to the other side. If the pipe runs down like in the picture cut a square in the wood for those pipes and have it run down. If this did not help then if you could put a picture because that would help me understand what it looks like at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Consider adding crown molding to the room. To handle the vertical pipes in the corner, seems like you could adapt the bottom of what's shown in the image below — for example by just having two flat boards forming half a box running down to the floor.

A quick Internet search should provide you with lots of sources of information about how to install this type of molding including youtube videos.

[image: image of installed crown molding]]